# AttributeError: 'MongoAlchemy' object has no attribute 'insert' MongoDB Flask MongoAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask, mongoalchemy

I am newbie to Flask restplus API's with mongoAlchemy , i am writing the curd opetaion for Flask restplus API's with mongoalchemy but getting the error while saving data to mongoalchemy
**

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py", line 313, in
wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\resource.py", line 44, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\app\api\controller\essential_controller.py", line 24, in post
    return essential_service.create_essential_service(data=data)
  File "c:\app\api\service\essential_service.py", line 10, in create_essential_service
    essentialData.save()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask_mongoalchemy\__init__.py", line 275, in save
    self._session.insert(self, safe=safe)
AttributeError: 'MongoAlchemy' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

**

MY code looks like below 
database file

```
from flask.ext.mongoalchemy import MongoAlchemy
from flask import Flask

mongododb = MongoAlchemy()

def init_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['MONGOALCHEMY_SERVER'] = 'localhost'
    app.config['MONGOALCHEMY_PORT'] = '27017'
    app.config['MONGOALCHEMY_DATABASE'] = 'publicvoicedb'
    mongododb.init_app(app)
    return app

class Location(mongododb.Document):
     type= mongododb.StringField()
     cooridantes =mongododb.StringField()


class Essential(mongododb.Document):
        subscriberName = mongododb.StringField()
        mobileNumber = mongododb.IntField()
        address = mongododb.StringField()
        pincode = mongododb.IntField()
        location = mongododb.DocumentField(Location)
        category = mongododb.StringField()
        request_date =mongododb.StringField()
        serviceType = mongododb.StringField() 
        issueDescription = mongododb.StringField()
```

controller

```
from flask import request
from flask_restplus import Resource

from service import essential_service
from models.dto import dto as EssentialDto

api = EssentialDto.EssentialDto.api
essential = EssentialDto.EssentialDto.essential

@api.route('/')
class EssentialController(Resource):
    @api.doc('Get all essential services')
    @api.marshal_list_with(essential, envelope='data')
    def get(self):
        """List all essential service"""
        return essential_service.get_all_service()

    @api.response(201, 'essential services successfully created.')
    @api.doc('create a new essential service')
    @api.expect(essential, validate=True)
    def post(self):
        """Creates a Essential service """
        data = request.json
        return essential_service.create_essential_service(data=data)
```

service layer

```
from database.db import mongododb
from database.db import Location
from database.db import Essential

def create_essential_service(data):
    print('data =', data)
    essentialData = Essential(subscriberName=data['subscriberName'],
    mobileNumber=data['mobileNumber'])

    essentialData.save()


def get_all_service():
    return Essential.query.filter(Essential.serviceType == 'PoliceService').first()

def get_by_service_type(serviceType):
    return Essential.query.filter_by(serviceType=serviceType).first()
```

Blue print

```
from flask_restplus import Api
from flask import Blueprint

from controller.essential_controller import api as essential_ns
'''from controller.author_controller import app as authors_ns'''

blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)

api = Api(blueprint,
          title='PublicVoice Backend service',
          version='0.0.1',
          description='PublicVoice Backend service'
          )

api.add_namespace(essential_ns, path='/essentials')
```

mange.py (this my main runner class)

```
import os
import unittest

from flask_script import Manager


from api import blueprint
from api.database import  db
from api.database.db import Location, Essential

app = db.init_app()
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

app.app_context().push()

manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def run():
    app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

requiremnet.txt

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
Flask-MongoAlchemy==0.7.2
flask-mongoengine==0.9.5
flask-restplus==0.10.1
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
Flask-Testing==0.8.0
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
```

Comment: i experience this too. i think its a bug on mongo alchemy. this error means that session is not initialized, the object `self._session` doesnt exist, this `self._session` should be `<class 'mongoalchemy.session.Session'>`, not `MongoAlchemy`, `MongoAlchemy` its like a big generic and ofc it doesnt have save, `Document`s have `save()`. normally if you use `db.init_app` it should initialize with a session, but the application factory pattern (your case and my case)  its not working. i've tested with a small flask app with one file and its working, even with the `db.init_app` executed later.